# Get image from url in database

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a database with image URL's. I have a stored procedure hat GET's the url's `(SP_GET_Image)` I want execute the stored proc then for each of the URL's get the image.

I want the actual image locally not the url.

Then for each image I want to save them locally. I have this code but want to know how do I save each image in a datarow.

I have started with the code.

```
Dim CMD as new sqlCommand("StoredProcedureName")
CMD.parameters("@Parameter1", sqlDBType.Int).value = Param_1_value

Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
CMD.Connection = connection
CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 300

'Fill the dataset'
 Dim DS as DataSet    
 adapter.Fill(ds)
 connection.Close()   

 'Now, read through your data:'
 For Each DR as DataRow in DS.Tables(0).rows
 '<-- Im not sure here how to GET EACH images locally saved.
Next
```

c# or vb help is fine.

The url looks like this :

`http://img.myCompany.net/p/1483/278227_20094171232290.jpg`

Comment: Can you provide the structure and sample values in those `DataRow`s returned by the SP? Is that will be a full url like `http://ww.google.com/logo.png`?

Comment: @Mathew Edited the original post

Comment: Is this your requirement? "You have some urls in your database. you have to save them in your project folder. is that it?"

Comment: @naveen I have url's but I want to save/download the image to another server, but for now I will download then locally. Because my images is in a database and I have a store proc that gets the top 10, I wanted to execute the store proc and each image(top 10) I wanted to save the actual image not the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile` in order to download and store the file on local machine or a remote server supplying a user name and password (if required). As you need to specify the file name when downloading, you can extract it from the URL with `SubString(URL.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)`

```
For Each DR as DataRow in DS.Tables(0).Rows
       Dim URL as String = DR("Your_URL_Column_Name").ToString()
       Dim Destination as String = "\\SERVERNAME\FolderName\"
       My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(URL, Destination & SubString(URL.LastIndexOf("/") + 1), "name", "password")
Next
```

Comment: I assume the "Your_URL_Column_Name" it the column name of the url that my stored proc returns?

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you download a list of images to a specified local path

```
    public void DownloadFiles(IEnumerable<string> urls, string path)
    {
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(urls, url =>
        {
            using (var downloader = new  WebClient())
            {
                var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(url));
                downloader.DownloadFile(url,filePath);   
            }
        });
    }
```

You can use it similar to this:

```
var urlList= DS.Tables[0].Rows
                         .Cast<DataRow>()
                         .Select(x => x["YourColumnNameOfUrl"].ToString());
DownloadFiles(urlList,"C:\Directory\Of\Ur\Choice\");
```

Comment: and if i want to download to an server i can change the url, filepath?

Comment: @user3458266 Yes, you can adjust the parameters as required. Run it from your server in a web application or such.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small utility function to help you with your task

```
Function SaveRemoteImage(remoteImageUrl As String) As Integer
    Try
        Dim request = WebRequest.Create(remoteImageUrl)
        Dim folderName = Server.MapPath("~/VB/Images/")
        Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Using stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Dim imageExtension = String.Empty
                Select Case response.ContentType.ToLower
                    Case "image/bmp",
                        "image/x-bmp",
                        "image/x-ms-bmp"
                        imageExtension = ".bmp"

                    Case "image/jpeg"
                        imageExtension = ".jpeg"

                    Case "image/gif"
                        imageExtension = ".gif"

                    Case "image/png"
                        imageExtension = ".png"

                    Case Else
                        imageExtension = ".png"
                End Select
                'renaming image name as GUID to avoid conflicts
                Dim imageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                ' Download the file
                Dim destinationPath = String.Concat(
                    folderName,
                    imageName,
                    imageExtension)
                Using tempFile = File.OpenWrite(destinationPath)
                    ' Remark: if the file is very big read it in chunks
                    ' to avoid loading it into memory
                    Dim buffer = New Byte(response.ContentLength - 1) {}
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    tempFile.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

I am not using the WebClient method as we need the correct Image Content-Type to get the local files extension.

Now, get all ImageUrls as an `IEnumerable(Of String)` from the `DataTable` and call it like this

```
Dim images = table.AsEnumerable().
    Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("ImageUrl"))
For Each remoteImage In images
    SaveRemoteImage(remoteImage)
Next
```

If you want some parallel programming magic, replace the `For Each` like this.

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(images,
    Function(remoteImage) SaveRemoteImage(remoteImage))
```